# How do I replace @each computed props when moving to Ember Octane

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have many `computed` props in my component like so:

```
@computed('foo.@each.bar')
get desiredState() {
  ...
}
```

And I still get complaints from linter:

```
Don't use computed properties with native classes. Use getters or @tracked properties instead.
```

I was able to replace the non `@each` props with `@tracked` but `@each` with `@tracked` doesn’t work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you need is to delete the `@computed` line.

getters *autotrack*, meaning that any tracked data consumed in the getter will be "tracked" by usages in the template.